# Breeze.Sharp - Need ability to specify UseDefaultCredentials in DataService's HttpClient construction

Tags: c#, breeze, breeze-sharp

As of 0.5.4 check-in, the `Breeze.Sharp/DataService.cs::InitializeHttpClient` method creates an `HttpClient` with the default constructor. My intranet breeze web api service has a .Net console application, which needs to be authenticated by the service using Windows authentication. In a pre-breeze universe, I would have created an `HttpClient` object that takes the following `HttpClientHandler` in the constructor, which would then send the user's credentials along with the http request:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
};
```

So the request here is to be able inject my own `HttpClient` into the `DataService`, or otherwise specify this setting when I construct an `EntityManager`.

For now, I have resolved the issue by modifying my own instance of the Breeze.Sharp library by updating the `DataService` constructor to optionally take in an `HttpClientHandler`, like so:

```
public DataService(String serviceName, HttpClientHandler handler = null) { ... }
```

I would prefer to keep using the main library so hopefully this issue gets tracked and resolved for everyone else. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated 6/3/2014

This is now supported in Breeze 0.5.5, available now

### Previous post

This makes sense, I'll try to look into it before the new release. ... and thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jay, I have integrated release 5.5 into my project and no longer need a private build. :)

Comment: Can you mark this as answered so that I can get it off my todo list? :)